# How to position a CompositedTransformFollower based on its child's size?

Tags: flutter

I'm using `CompositedTransformTarget` and `CompositedTransformFollower` to display an `OverlayEntry`. How can I position the `CompositedTransformFollower` relative to the `CompositedTransformTarget`, i.e. how can I align its bottom to the top-center of the target in order to display it horizontally centered above the target, while maintaining interactivity (i.e. hit tests on the child should work)?

I tried to calculate the `offset` to give to `CompositedTransformFollower`, but I cannot do the correct calculation, because at that time I don't have the size of the child.

Sample Code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('test')),
        body: Center(child: OverlayButton()),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OverlayButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OverlayButtonState createState() => _OverlayButtonState();
}

class _OverlayButtonState extends State<OverlayButton> {
  OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
  final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();
  bool _overlayIsShown = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if (_overlayIsShown) {
      _hideOverlay();
    }
  }

  void _showOverlay() {
    if (_overlayIsShown) return;
    _overlayEntry = _createOverlayEntry();
    Overlay.of(context).insert(_overlayEntry);
    _overlayIsShown = true;
  }

  void _hideOverlay() {
    _overlayIsShown = false;
    _overlayEntry.remove();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: _layerLink,
      child: RaisedButton(child: Text('Open Overlay'), onPressed: _showOverlay),
    );
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var anchorSize = renderBox.size;
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      // TODO: dynamically use the correct child width / height for
      // positioning us correctly on top + centered on the anchor
      var childWidth = 200.0;
      var childHeight = 40.0;
      var childOffset =
          Offset(-(childWidth - anchorSize.width) / 2, -(childHeight));
      return Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          CompositedTransformFollower(
            link: _layerLink,
            offset: childOffset,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text('close'),
              onPressed: _hideOverlay,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to fork the Follower widget for that. I've made one here https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_portal/blob/rework/lib/src/custom_follower.dart

Answer (score 4):

**General answer:**

It looks like we want to know the exact size of a child, before deciding where to place the child. There's a widget made for this purpose, called `CustomSingleChildLayout`. Also, if you need to layout multiple children, you should check out the slightly more complex version, `CustomMultiChildLayout`.

**For this case:**

First you need to insert a `CustomSingleChildLayout` in the `OverlayEntry` you are building, for example, I added 2 lines here:

```
  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var anchorSize = renderBox.size;
    return OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
      return CompositedTransformFollower(
        link: _layerLink,
        child: CustomSingleChildLayout(     // # Added Line 1 #
          delegate: MyDelegate(anchorSize), // # Added Line 2 #
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('close'),
            onPressed: _hideOverlay,
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
```

Then let's create a delegate that handles your business logic. Notice I've also created a parameter to take in your "anchorSize":

```
class MyDelegate extends SingleChildLayoutDelegate {
  final Size anchorSize;

  MyDelegate(this.anchorSize);

  @override
  BoxConstraints getConstraintsForChild(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    // we allow our child to be smaller than parent's constraint:
    return constraints.loosen();
  }

  @override
  Offset getPositionForChild(Size size, Size childSize) {
    print("my size: $size");
    print("childSize: $childSize");
    print("anchor size being passed in: $anchorSize}");
    // todo: where to position the child? perform calculation here:
    return Offset(anchorSize.width, childSize.height / 2);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRelayout(_) => true;
}
```

As you can see, in the `getPositionForChild` method, we are able to gather all the information needed for calculating an offset. After calculating, we can just return that offset and `CustomSingleChildLayout` will take care of the placement.

To expand on this idea, you probably don't even need `CompositedTransformFollower` anymore, you can just do a full-screen overlay and calculate the offset that way.